# Need some help compiling "Hello World" in g++

Tags: c++, linux

I recently took the plunge into Debian and wanted to begin translating my code over from visual studio to vim/make/G++.

I'm running Debian wheezy and have installed G++ 4.7.2 (came with debian, can't change it - not enough download quota). I've created a file `main.cpp` and placed the following into it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I `cd`'d into the directory of that file and ran `g++ main.cpp -o hello`, which didn't produce any errors or outputs. Then, when I type `. hello` I get this error:

> bash: .: hello: cannot execute binary file

I tried running `chmod 777 hello` thinking this might be a permission problem but that didn't help either. I'm thinking I might have inadvertently produced an object file instead, but I don't know how to check..

Comment: How you execute by `. hello`? it is `./hello`.

Comment: `chmod +x hello` and `./hello` should work !

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. When I run `. hello` I get `Cannot execute binary file` and when I write `./hello` it works. But I've just run `chmod +x hello` as well so now I don't know what fixed it. If `. hello` is wrong then shouldn't it tell me so?

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz It does so. The part of the shell responsible for sourcing a script tells you that it is not able to execute a binary file.

Comment: You should take the habit of compiling with `g++ -Wall -g hello.cpp -o hello`: the `-Wall` gives almost all warnings (very useful), and the `-g` produces a *debuggable* executable (for the `gdb` debugger).

Comment: @Basile, that `-Wall` flag has always annoyed me since it's clearly _not_ all (I tend to use `-Wall -Wextra`). It really should be renamed `-Wmost` :-)

Comment: Agreed, but `-Wall`  is much better than nothing....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
. hello
```

tells the bash shell to run the `hello` *script* in the context of the current shell (i.e., it tries to *source* the script), which is why `bash` is giving you an error. Methinks you meant to execute:

```
./hello
```

It's not actually `bash` telling your you file isn't executable, rather it's telling you it cannot interpret that binary file as a script. The `chmod` is irrelevant here because successfully generated executables out of the gcc toolchain are *already* executable.

For more details on `bash` sourcing, see the man page, relevant section copied below:

> `.      filename [arguments]`
> `source filename [arguments]`
>
> Read  and  execute  commands  from filename in the current shell environment and return the exit status of the last command executed from filename.
>
> If filename does not contain a slash, file names in PATH are used to find the directory containing filename.
>
> The file searched for in PATH need not be executable.  When bash is not in posix mode, the current directory is searched  if no file is found in PATH.
>
> If the sourcepath option to the shopt builtin command is turned off, the PATH is not searched.
>
> If any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when filename is executed.  Otherwise the positional parameters are unchanged.
>
> The return status is the status of the last command exited within the script (0 if no commands  are  executed), and false if filename is not found or cannot be read.

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz Can you accept this answer by clicking the checkmark next to it? It let's the community know that you have found a sufficient answer.

Comment: @0x499602D2 my bad, I wasn't able to accept the answer because it was posted to quickly and then I forgot about it...